# How to persist HttpSession across cross origin calls in java spring rest?

Tags: spring, reactjs, session

I have my spring rest api running at `localhost:8080/api` and a react app consuming this api at `localhost:3000` and i am trying to persist info in case the user refreshes the page.

It works fine if my frontend code resides in the spring app itself but not when it runs on a different port.

All the help online points to spring security (or doesnt work for me) , is there no way to do it without spring security ?

Here is the relevant code.

**Backend** 
`src/com/config/InitConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com")
public class InitConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

`src/com/config/Initializer.java`

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {InitConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("inside the initializer");
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

`src/com/controller/UserController.java`

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService ;

    @RequestMapping(value="/users",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<User>> getAllUsers(HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println("Inside users controller ") ;
        System.out.println(req.getSession().getId()) ;
        ArrayList<User> arr = new ArrayList<User>() ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
            arr.add(new User("sarvagya" , 1)) ;
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ArrayList<User>>(arr , HttpStatus.OK) ;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getCurrent(HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println("Inside home controller ") ;
        System.out.println(req.getSession().getId()) ;
        System.out.println("CurrentUser is " + req.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser")) ;
        User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser") ;
        if(user == null) return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK) ; 
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user , HttpStatus.OK) ;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/users/current" , method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getCurrentUser(HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println(req.getSession().getId()) ;
        System.out.println("CurrentUser is " + req.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser")) ;
        User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser") ;
        if(user == null) return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) ; 
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user , HttpStatus.OK) ;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="users/login" , method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByEmail(@RequestBody User user , HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println("Inside java controller " + user) ;
        User newUser = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) ;
        System.out.println(newUser) ;
        if(newUser == null || !newUser.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            newUser = null ;
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(newUser, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) ;
        }
        System.out.println("Successful login") ;
        // successful login
        req.getSession().setAttribute("currentUser", newUser) ;
        System.out.println(req.getSession().getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(newUser, HttpStatus.OK) ;
    }
}
```

**Frontend**

`UserService.js`

```
export const userService = {
    login : (user) => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method : 'POST' , 
            body : JSON.stringify(user) , 
            headers : {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            } , 
            credentials : 'include'
        }
        return fetch(`${BASE_API_URL}/users/login`,requestOptions).then(response => {
            // valid credentials
            if(response.ok) {
                return response.json() ;
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(response.statusText) ;
            }
        }).then(data => {return data}) ;
    } , 
    logout : () => {} , 
    getUser : () => {
        return fetch(`${BASE_API_URL}/users/current` , {method : 'GET' , headers : {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}}).then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response.json()
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(response.statusText) ;
            }
        }).then(data => {return data}) ;
    } 
}
```

I am just trying to set a `currentUser` attribute in the HttpSession object on a successful login and get that info between page refreshes. I am able to login so the cross origin is working i guess , only problem is that my session id is different on every request i make so the info is lost on page refreshes. Is my setup wrong or is that not the way to work with sessions with cross origin requests ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for Session object, best practice is to use token based authentication system where JWT or similar encrypted tokens you can persist in your browser local storage for the time being and destroy it on logout/time out time.

Comment: go through following link for the basic idea http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/12/07/react-redux-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example

Comment: I am aware of that. I already have a spring + angular project running and i am building a react frontend to consume the api (but it runs on a separate port) , hence dont really want to touch the backend except the cross origin config. My question is only about if it is possible to do this with session object or not.